# Issues decoding strings from Xml

Tags: c#, .net, xml, html-encode

I have been given a large quantity of Xml's where I need to pull out parts of the text elements and reuse it for other purposes. (I am using XDocument to pull Xml data).

But, how do I decode the text contained in the elements? What is even the formatting used here? A few examples:

```
"What is the meaning of this&amp;reg; asks Sonny."
"The big centre cost 1&amp;#190; million pounds"
"... lost it. &amp;#174; The next ..."
```

I have tried `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` but that did not do the trick. If I decode twice the "&reg;" turns into a ® which is obviously not right.

Looks like &#174; are line breaks. The &reg; are probably question marks. The 190 one, I don't even know. Perhaps a dot or comma?

Any ideas would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does appear that the strings you show have been HTML encoded, and then XML encoded (or HTML again).

It *is* correct that `&amp;reg;` -> `&reg;` -> `®` (the registered trademark symbol) per [the ISO Latin-1 entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - `&amp;#174;` should behave the same way

Similarly `&amp#190;` would turn into a fraction representing three quarters.

Comment: The issue is then that the result makes no sense once I decode the text. When decoded twice it becomes obvious that the ®-symbols, really should be question marks.

Comment: But looking through the results, it may be that this is the only one that is not working. Decoding twice on the others seems to work. Will test a bit more.

Comment: Yep, everything else works. Will accept this as an answer and do a .Replace on that symbol.